# Getting page title of site in Page Layout

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2013, page-layout, publishing-page

I want to display title of site in Page Layout. How do I do that?
Let's say I have a site with 3 pages and on each page I want to display title of my site. Is there a code that I can use in Page Layout to do this job?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add

```
<SharePoint:FieldValue FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
```

for Page title or

```
<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />
```

for Site title

in one of the ContentPlaceHolders in the PageLayout, for the body in the

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceholderID="PlaceHolderMain">
```

Comment: I pasted Site Title code inside PlaceHolderMain in my Page Layout but getting error "Unknown server tag 'SharePoint:ProjectProperty'". Looks like some assembly or reference is missing which I need to add in page layout!?

Comment: <%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using Design manager, using the following snippet:

```
<h1 id="custom-pagetitle">
<!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">-->
    <!--CS: Start Page Field: Title Snippet-->
    <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="PageFieldFieldValue" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
    <!--MS:<PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue FieldName="fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247" runat="server">-->
    <!--ME:</PageFieldFieldValue:FieldValue>-->
    <!--CE: End Page Field: Title Snippet-->
<!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
</h1>
```

In [MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822367.aspx#UnderstandMarkup) you can find this explanation of the comment tags above:

> A snippet contains four basic sections:
>
> Header with starting <div> and
>   <!--CS> tags (except custom ASP.NET snippets, which are not wrapped in
>   a <div> tag)
>
> SharePoint markup where snippets are enclosed in <!--MS>
>   start and <!--ME> end tags
>
> HTML preview enclosed in <!--PS> start and
>   <!--PE> end tags
>
> Footer with closing <!--CE> and </div> tags.

Comment: Please explain why the MS/CS/ME/SPM stuff on each row?

Answer (score 1):

In regards to adding a page title directly on a html page layout, the following code works when you place it anywhere within the content placeholder PlaceHolderMain.

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:FieldValue FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>-->
```

Answer (score 0):

All @robertLingren  was very close re the site title. For the layout pages
you can use aspx markup but you need to wrap in the MS markup syntax - the code below I have tested and it works

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" />-->
```

Comment: The question is about page layouts though, but great input for layout pages