# How to add SharePoint Site Title to a Site Page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I have many Site Pages that I would like to include that Site Title in the text on the Site Pages. Is this possible?

I'd like to be able to do it many times with in the Site Page.

For example, the Site Page is the name of my University. Can I reference the Site Page name every time I want to display.

Why? So when I save the Site as a Template. New Site will reference the new Site Names.

(I have Designer, but am trying to avoid using. Also, I am not using a Page Layout/Master)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code to display Site Title on each Page.

**Please follow steps:**

1.Open your Master Page by using SharePoint Designer.

2.Edit your Master Page

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderSiteName" runat="server">

    <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~site/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitle"><SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server" /></SharePoint:SPLinkButton>

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

*`OR INSERT`*

```
<SharePoint:ProjectProperty Property="Title" runat="server"/>
```

Here are two similar cases for your reference:

- [Getting page title of site in Page Layout](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/76463/getting-page-title-of-site-in-page-layout)
- [SharePoint Site Title on each page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/bee30631-1737-4bb0-81e3-dc817a1720c4/sharepoint-site-title-on-each-page?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your page is a classic one ?

Since your page is not using a masterpage, you will need to edit all of your pages and add a [script editor or content editor](https://www.spguides.com/script-editor-web-part-sharepoint-2016/) to be able to do what you want.

On your script editor, add this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
let pname = document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerText;
document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerText = "TEXT YOU WANT TO APPEND"+pname;
```

I tested it out real quick in our tenant,
[image]

Hope it helps! Happy SharePointing!